# Appending the contents of a HTMLCollection to Body

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to:

1. Parse a HTML string to a DOM object
2. Extract the paragraphs (10 of them in this case)
3. Append extracted paragraphs to body

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function _parse(html_str_or_obj)
    {
        var elem_obj, elem_dom_obj;

        //Convert to DOM element
        elem_obj = document.createElement("div");
        elem_obj.innerHTML = html_str_or_obj;
        elem_dom_obj = elem_obj.firstChild;

        return elem_dom_obj;
    }

    var html_str = '<div id="body-wrapper">\
      <div id="container-1">\
        <div id="container-1x"><div id="container-2x"><div id="container-3x"><p>First Paragraph</p></div></div></div>\
        <p>This is the first container - Line 1</p>\
        <p>This is the first container - Line 2</p>\
        <p>This is the first container - Line 3</p>\
      </div>\
      <div id="container-2">\
        <p>This is the second container - Line 1</p>\
        <p>This is the second container - Line 2</p>\
        <p>This is the second container - Line 3</p>\
        <p>This is the second container - Line 4</p>\
      </div>\
        <div id="container-3">\
        <p>This is the third container - Line 1</p>\
        <p>This is the third container - Line 2</p>\
      </div>\
    </div>';
    var elem_body_obj = document.body;
    var elem_obj = _parse(html_str);
    var elem_p_obj = elem_obj.getElementsByTagName('p');

    for(var i = 0; i < elem_p_obj.length; i++)
    {
        elem_body_obj.appendChild(elem_p_obj[i]);
    }
});
```

It works up to the point when I append the elements. Instead of 10 paragraphs, it only appends 5. Not sure what is going on.

When I use `console.log(elem_p_obj)`, it shows me a HTMLCollection with only 5 elements. However, when I comment out `elem_body_obj.appendChild(elem_p_obj[i]);` from the for loop, it outputs 10 elements as normal.

I want to append all 10 paragraphs, but something seems to be wrong somewhere.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o3gutw2e/3/.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`element.getElementsByTagName()` returns a live node list. This means your list is shrinking after you append each item to the body.

Instead of iterating through the list, you can simply keep calling `.appendChild()` on the first element for however long the original size of the list is.

```
while (elem_p_obj.length > 0)
{
    elem_body_obj.appendChild(elem_p_obj[0]);
}
```

Live node lists tend to introduce a lot of unexpected bugs in an application, so I would recommend using your original solution with `.querySelectorAll()` instead.

```
var elem_p_obj = elem_obj.querySelectorAll('p');
for(var i = 0; i < elem_p_obj.length; i++)
{
    elem_body_obj.appendChild(elem_p_obj[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I'll also look at using querySelectorAll for operations like this. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

As i just ran into problems using a live list, I'll would provide my solutions as well.

using the HTMLCollection live list...

```js
let elemToAppendto = document.getElementById('some-elem');

while (htmlCollection.firstChild instanceof HTMLElement) {
    elemToAppendto.appendChild(htmlCollection.firstChild);
}
```

or if you want to avoid the live list...

```js
let elemToAppendto = document.getElementById('some-elem');

let htmlCollectionArray = Array.from(htmlCollection)
for (const child of htmlCollectionArray) {
  elemToAppendto.append(child);
}
```